# How to compare two String Source and destination with fullname in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, alexa-voice-service

Compare two string with third-string like JSON Array full name

```
var source = intentObj.slots.toPlazaName.value.toString(); // Jaipur 
var destination = intentObj.slots.fromPlazaName.value.toString(); // Kishangarh
```

match with this  `"FullName": "Jaipur - Kishangarh Section",`

My response

```
{
            "projectid": 10,
            "FullName": "Kishangarh -Ajmer- Beawar",
            "piu": "PIU-Ajmer",
            "NumberofLanes": "6L",
            "NHNo_New": "8",
            "NHNo_Old": "8",
            "Total_Length": 92,
            "state_name": "Rajasthan"
        },
        {
            "projectid": 15,
            "FullName": "Reengus - Sikar",
            "piu": "PIU-Sikar",
            "NumberofLanes": "4L",
            "NHNo_New": "52",
            "NHNo_Old": "11",
            "Total_Length": 44,
            "state_name": "Rajasthan"
        },
        {
            "projectid": 20,
            "FullName": "Rajsamand - Gangapur - Bhilwara",
            "piu": "PIU-Chittorgarh",
            "NumberofLanes": "4L",
            "NHNo_New": "758",
            "NHNo_Old": "76B",
            "Total_Length": 87.25,
            "state_name": "Rajasthan"
        },
```

my create function

```
function findSourceDestination(source, destination, callback) {
    var matchPlazas = [];
    var projectFullName = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < nhai_response.GetALexDataInJSONResult.length; i++) {
        // console.log(nhai_response.GetALexDataInJSONResult[i]["FullName"]);
        if (nhai_response.GetALexDataInJSONResult[i]["FullName"].includes(source)) {
            // console.log("source " + nhai_response.GetALexDataInJSONResult[i]["FullName"]);
            projectFullName.push(nhai_response.GetALexDataInJSONResult[i]);
        }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < projectFullName.length; j++) {
        if (projectFullName[j]["FullName"].includes(destination)) {
            console.log('----------------' +projectFullName[j]["FullName"] + '----------destination '+ destination +'------------');
            matchPlazas.push(projectFullName[j]);
        } 

    }

    callback(matchPlazas);
}
```

I have full name string another. I have two another string. I want to match source string with my full name first-word destination will match or contain with full name, not the first string like the source string.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well your questions, and you need the source to be the first part of FullName, and destination needs to be in the rest of FullName, this function makes it

```
function findSourceDestination(source, destination, callback) {
    var matchPlazas = [];
    var projectFullName = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < nhai_response.GetALexDataInJSONResult.length; i++) {
        let fullName = nhai_response.GetALexDataInJSONResult[i]["FullName"];
        let fullNameParts = fullName.split("-");
        if (fullNameParts[0].trim().includes(source) && fullName.includes(fullName)) {
            matchPlazas.push(nhai_response.GetALexDataInJSONResult[i]);
        }
    }

    callback(matchPlazas);
}
```

Comment: fullNameParts[0].trim().includes(source) && fullName.includes(fullName) is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
   // no search in progress, start our search at the end
                     _pos = Length - 1;
                 }
-                else if (!wasLive && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
+                else if (!wasLive && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
                 {
                     // Handles up up up enter up
                     // Do nothing
 @@ -167,7 +167,7 @@ private string MoveToPrevious(string search)

         private bool SearchDoesntMatch(string search)
         {
-            return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search) && GetHistoryText(_pos).IndexOf(search) == -1;
+            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search) && GetHistoryText(_pos).IndexOf(search) == -1;
         }

         private string GetHistoryMatch(string search)
```